# The Pain Went Down

Tags: phrase-usage, informal-language, figurative-language

I have a question about the usage of the phrase "*go down*".

According to this dictionary [definition](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/go) for go down (3a+b), I could use "*go down*" like this:

> The swelling went down.
>   His fever went down.

But, on google searches, I also found this:

> The pain went down.

But dictionary examples similar to "*the pain went down*" cannot be found.  So, is "*the pain went down*" poor usage?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary examples are not going to be able to include all usages.

However, to my native American English year, it's understandable but I wouldn't use it. A related possibility would be:

> The level of pain went down.

or

> The pain lessened.

or

> The pain decreased.

Answer (score 1):

In this usage, *to go down* exactly means *to decrease*.  It's perfectly acceptable usage.